# R leaflet package not properly displaying special characters?

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using the `leaflet` package in `r` to make a geographical map. I'm using the `addLabelOnlyMarkers` function to add the location name for certain locations. Some of those location names include special characters like "é" which are not properly displayed by `leaflet`. Instead I get nonsense: for example "é" gets replaced by "Ã©".

I've already figured out that this is a UTF-8 encoding problem. See https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html for more info.

My question is: how do I fix this in my `r` code. Here is the code I'm using:

```
leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerBackground") %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(
      data = mySpatialPointsDataFrame,
      label = ~columnContainingNames,
      labelOptions = labelOptions(
        noHide = TRUE,
        textOnly = TRUE,
        textsize = "15px",
        direction = "center",
        style = list("color" = "white", "font-style" = "italic")
      )
    )
```

Please note that the characters are displaying properly when viewing the data part of mySpatialPointsDataFrame in R. So the problem happens when `leaflet` tries to put that data on a map.

Answer (score 1):

sorry I am one point away from being able to comment!

Can you use

```
~paste(html in here)
```

I know leaflet can read html in the popup menu, although not sure about in the label.

It would mean doing it manually, but; I am sure you could do some fancy stuff using regex to find all the e-acute (or whatever symbol) and replace them with the HTML code for the desired symbol.